# How to solve ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00919?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sas, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem after connecting to Oracle. Here's part of my code:

```
%let rokmies= 202305;

proc sql noprint;
connect to oracle(user=&rdo_usr. password=&rdo_pwd.
path="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)( HOST = 122.137.78.156)(PORT = 1831))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID=RDO)))"
); 

create table metody as
select 
  METHOD, COST
from connection to Oracle 
(
SELECT 
  rech_sp_method as METHOD,
  rm_cost as COST,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rech_sp_method ORDER BY  rdo_enddate desc,rdo_namestamp desc, rdo_status ) as rn
FROM ptk_kom.sp_recharge_method
)
where rn =1
;

disconnect from oracle;
quit;


proc sql noprint;
connect to oracle(user=&rdo_usr. password=&rdo_pwd.
path="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)( HOST = 122.137.78.156)(PORT = 1831))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID=RDO)))"
); 

create table plik_recharges as
select * from connection to Oracle 
(
select ACCOUNT, COSTS, METHOD as day
from ptk_pop.recharge_usage 
where (balance_types = '6' or balance_types like '6,%' or balance_types like '%,6,%' or balance_types like '%,6' 
or balance_types = '2421' or balance_types like '2421,%' or balance_types like '%,2421,%' or balance_types like '%,2421')
and substr(rdo_namestamp, 1, 6) = &rokmies.

);
```

And my whole error reads:

```
ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00919: niepoprawna funkcja. SQL statement: select ACCOUNT,
       COSTS, METHOD as day from ptk_pop.recharge_usage where (balance_types 
       = '6' or balance_types like '6,%' or balance_types like '%,6,%' or balance_types like '%,6' or balance_types = '2421' or 
       balance_types like '2421,%' or balance_types like '%,2421,%' or balance_types like '%,2421') and substr(rdo_namestamp, 1, 6) 
       = &rokmies..
```

(rokmies= 202305)
could someone please help in the solution?

I checked if all balance_types must have all these conditions, but unfortunately it did not give anything.

Comment: Please post the actual SQL statement. `select * from connection to Oracle (<sql code>)` is not a valid syntax and looks like a function call (`"connection to Oracle"(args)`) which may be the issue

Comment: @astentx The `select * from connection to Oracle (<sql code>)` is valid SAS syntax for calling Oracle SQL. See the documentacion: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n05b4mygsvt845n1vnr6r5kchbjf.htm

Comment: @yabwon Thank you for the link. This was originally posted as a standalone statement, which was confusing Oracle code.

Comment: Thanks for info! I saw only the version with `select * from connection to Oracle (<sql code>)`.

Answer (score 2):

day is a reserved word.  If you want a column named day, put it inside double quotes.

```
...
select ACCOUNT, COSTS, METHOD as "day"
...
```

Comment: For Oracle table to be created it is not required. [Quote](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA): *Nonquoted identifiers cannot be Oracle SQL [reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612)... Oracle SQL keywords are not reserved. However, Oracle uses them internally in specific ways...* Other answers have working fiddles with this column name "as is"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `select * from connection to Oracle (<sql code>)` query is syntactically valid SAS call to Oracle SQL. See the documentation: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n05b4mygsvt845n1vnr6r5kchbjf.htm

Second, as far as I know the `substr()` function returns character and for oracle the `202305` looks like an integer. Try adding the following: `%tslit(&rokmies.)` which will resolve to `'202305'`.

I would also check if the `METHOD` is not some sort of qracle keyword, try to change it from `METHOD` to `sp_METHOD`.

P.S. Powodzenia.

Comment: Could also have `%let rokmies= '202305';`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @astentx in comments, you have invalid syntax, use this query instead :

```
create table plik_recharges as
select ACCOUNT, COSTS, METHOD as day
from recharge_usage 
where (balance_types = '6' or balance_types like '6,%' or balance_types like '%,6,%' or balance_types like '%,6' 
or balance_types = '2421' or balance_types like '2421,%' or balance_types like '%,2421,%' or balance_types like '%,2421')
and substr(rdo_namestamp, 1, 6) = &rokmies
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nJZ4v507)

Comment: I try and i've got 2 errors: ERROR 73-322: AS expected, and ERROR 22-322: Syntax error. One of the following was expected: name, string in parentheses, numerical constant, fixed date-time, no data, BTRIM, INPUT, PUT, SUBSTRING, USER.

Comment: Not sure what you have tried, can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries look to be syntactically invalid and you may need to remove `connection to Oracle` from them (unless this is required by your SAS pre-processor and the pre-processor removes it; but it is certainly invalid when Oracle process the SQL):

```sql
create table metody as
select METHOD, COST
from   (
  SELECT rech_sp_method as METHOD,
         rm_cost as COST,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rech_sp_method ORDER BY  rdo_enddate desc,rdo_namestamp desc, rdo_status ) as rn
  FROM   ptk_kom.sp_recharge_method
)
where rn = 1;
```

and:

```sql
create table plik_recharges as
select *
from   (
  select ACCOUNT,
         COSTS,
         METHOD as day
  from   ptk_pop.recharge_usage 
  where  (  ',' || balance_types || ',' LIKE '%,6,%'
         or ',' || balance_types || ',' LIKE '%,2421,%'
         )
  and    substr(rdo_namestamp, 1, 6) = &rokmies
);
```

(and not leave a blank line before the final `);` as your pre-processor appears to be taking a blank line as the end of the statement as the final closing bracket does not appear in the error message.)